# python pandas: Rename a series within a dataframe?

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, series

I'm using python pandas for data analysis and I want to change the name of a series in a dataframe.

This works, but it seems very inefficient:

```
AA = pandas.DataFrame( A )
for series in A:
    AA[A_prefix+series] = A[series]
    del A[series]
```

Is there a way to change the series name in place?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, you can use the [rename](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) method:

```
In [11]: df = DataFrame({"A": [1,2], "B": [3,4]})

In [12]: df.rename(columns={"A": "series formerly known as A"})
Out[12]: 
   series formerly known as A  B
0                           1  3
1                           2  4
```

This doesn't change `df`, though:

```
In [13]: df
Out[13]: 
   A  B
0  1  3
1  2  4
```

You can get that behaviour if you want using `inplace`:

```
In [14]: df.rename(columns={"A": "series formerly known as A"}, inplace=True)
Out[14]: 
   series formerly known as A  B
0                           1  3
1                           2  4

In [15]: df
Out[15]: 
   series formerly known as A  B
0                           1  3
1                           2  4
```