# Creating pandas Dataframe and renaming change 0.10.0 to 0.13.1

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently debugging some legacy code to work with newer versions of pandas. I have some information in a Series  that I want to build into a new Dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(old_series, columns=['A'])  # create new dataframe from Series
```

in 0.10.0 this basically creates a new Dataframe with the column name set to "A".   In 10.13.1 it seems to try to do something different as it gives me an empty DataFrame.

Can do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(old_series)
#pseudo_code to find name of column and then use
#pd.rename as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201099/python-pandas-rename-a-series-within-a-dataframe
```

anyone know of a shorter way.   Don't really care what the Series used to be called,  just want to get it in new DataFrame with heading "A"

Not sure if I was misusing the syntax for my old code or if this is a bug in 0.13.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an undocumented 'feature' that was also not tested, and so did change in 0.13.0.
It violates consistency of the way the `columns` kw works in the `DataFrame` constructor, that is, it `reindexes` the resulting set, not `renames`.

Use `to_frame` to change the name of the series if needed.

```
In [8]: DataFrame(Series([1,2,3],name='foo'),columns=['A'])
Out[8]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A]
Index: []

[0 rows x 1 columns]

In [9]: Series([1,2,3],name='foo').to_frame()
Out[9]: 
   foo
0    1
1    2
2    3

[3 rows x 1 columns]

In [10]: Series([1,2,3],name='foo').to_frame(name='A')
Out[10]: 
   A
0  1
1  2
2  3

[3 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks.   Makes sense.   .to_frame method not available in pandas 10.0  though.  I am still going backwards and forwards to make sure there are no other bugs so the two liner proposed by @Will is probably the elegant solution in meantime for me.   Thanks again for pandas and great support.

Comment: Wait, so this isn't a bug??

Comment: no it was wrong before. (could have been better documented to this 'change'), but unfortunately their weren't any tests, so it didn't get caught till after 0.13.1

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(old_series)
df.columns = ["A"]
```

Comment: correct, would still like to know if i was using the DataFrame construction syntax incorrectly.   Have approximately 3,000 lines of code to check for similar sysntax

Comment: Hang on, is your question related to the column name setting or to the dataframe getting constructed empty?

Comment: mainly about the empty created one... As said my legacy code is broken so I want to check if the construction is supported in pandas going forward.   Gut feeling is that it should be supported?

Comment: OK. I misunderstood but definitely yes, you can construct dataframe from series. Pop me a sample of your series data and we'll see if there's something funny going on.

Comment: no problem.   noted that in 0.10 Series type was "pandas.core.series.Series"  in 0.13.1 came in as "pandas.core.series.TimeSeries".   Still think this might be a bug in 0.13.1 but don't have time to prove it now.    Got a bunch of other problems to fix.    Will mark your answer as answer.   Going to leave it open for a day or so though in case pandas developer have a look at it and have a definitive answer if I were misusing the syntax.

Comment: Series and TimeSeries are quite different. We need to see the data you're using to comment on how it will be converted/used/formatted etc.