# Updated Pandas don`t understand new behaviour

Tags: python, pandas

I've recently updated to Pandas 0.13 from 0.12 when moving to a new computer.`However I`m getting some odd behaviour.  Specifically when trying to create a new DataFrame from an existing DataFrame as shown in the code below:

```
WRF_s = pd.DataFrame(WRF.d, index=ts, columns=list('W'))
```

Where WRF is my existing DataFrame with one column ('d').  I have the old computer here, and am running the code off the same files; on the old version it works and in the new version it fills the new DataFrame all with NaN.  Has anyone had a similar experience?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This works.  Thanks!  DO you know why this changed?  I can't accept this as the answer as a comment.

Comment: This was an undocumented API that 'worked' prior to 0.13, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984862/creating-pandas-dataframe-and-renaming-change-0-10-0-to-0-13-1/21987332#21987332

Answer (score 0):

As behzad answered above, using `WRF.d.value` fixed the issue.